# Atualizar diversos registros com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Supondo que tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
UPDATE tb_foo SET idoso = 1 WHERE idade > 65
```

Para realizar este mesmo processo em linq, tenho

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = contexto.Foos.Where(e => e.Idade > 65);
foreach(var item in foos)
{
      item.Idoso = true;
}
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Esta é a maneira mais performática de realizar um update de vários registros na base de dados utilizando linq?

[A consulta é executada quando chega no `foreach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217570/4223174), mas os `updates` são realizados no `SaveChanges`, gerando assim um processo a mais do que a execução do `Update` com uma cláusula `where` na própria base de dados (ou utilizando ADO.NET). Este pensamento está correto?

Comment: No `.SaveChanges()` ele vai executar vários updates. O EF não suporta o update em lote não. Vou tentar achar um texto que li sobre isso e coloco aqui se conseguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer o update, peguei o código abaixo [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314666/3517631):

```
var ls=new int[]{2,3,4};
using (var db=new SomeDatabaseContext())
{
    var some= db.SomeTable.Where(x=>ls.Contains(x.friendid)).ToList();
    some.ForEach(a=>a.status=true);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}

using (var db=new SomeDatabaseContext())
{
     db.SomeTable
       .Where(x=>ls.Contains(x.friendid))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(a=>a.status=true);

     db.SubmitChanges();
}

using (var db=new SomeDatabaseContext())
{
    foreach (var some in db.SomeTable.Where(x=>ls.Contains(x.friendid)).ToList())
    {
        some.status=true;
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Coloquei mais para você ver que existem várias formas de se fazer. O fato é que nenhuma delas vai fazer o update com `where id > 30`

O `.ForEach()` nada mais é que um for each feito no resultado. A única vantagem é que fica mais limpo usando ele.

Eu particularmente quando preciso fazer um update simples em vários registros eu utilizo um procedimento do banco de dados mesmo. Tudo depende da sua infra, capacidade do BD e do servidor de aplicação.

**ATUALIZANDO**

Em relação a uma posição oficial da Microsoft sobre isso eu não sei dizer se existe. Até meados do ano passado (se não me falha a memória) eu procurei alguma coisa e não achei nada.

Você pode tentar alguns projeto feitos por terceiros para fazer isso:

[Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#entity-framework-extended-library)

[Entity Framework Extensions (Multiple entity updates)](http://efe.codeplex.com/)

Quando existir uma solução para isso nativa do EF provavelmente esses projetos mesmo vão anunciar.

Comment: Sim sim, @Ricardo. A dúvida maior era sobre o comportamento do linq. Você tem alguma fonte sobre " fato é que nenhuma delas vai fazer o update com where id > 30"? Procurei no MSDN e em alguns livros de referência mas não consegui encontrar este comportamento

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com o pouco que sei